# Run-time error in my realization of deque in Python3

Tags: deque

Could you please help me to find an error in the realization of deque? There is a restriction on the number of possible elements in the deque (namely 100).

I suppose that my code has mistakes because it runs out with a run-time error when I am trying to pass it on the contest. 
The problem is that when I seek to 
find this mistake manually I can't get such an error.
Here is my code:

```
def push_front(dequeue, elem):
    global dequeuestart
    dequeue[dequeuestart] = elem
    dequeuestart -= 1
    print('ok')

def push_back(dequeue, elem):
    global dequeueend
    dequeue[dequeueend] = elem
    dequeueend += 1
    print('ok')

def pop_front(dequeue):
    global dequeuestart
    dequeuestart += 1
    return dequeue[dequeuestart]

def pop_back(dequeue):
    global dequeueend
    dequeueend -= 1
    return dequeue[dequeueend]

def front(dequeue):
    return dequeue[dequeuestart + 1]

def back(dequeue):
    return dequeue[dequeueend - 1]

def size(dequeue):
    return dequeueend - dequeuestart - 1

def clear(dequeue):
    global dequeuestart
    global dequeueend
    dequeuestart = 99
    dequeueend = 100
    print('ok')

def exit(dequeue):
    print('bye')


dequeue = ['None' for i in range(200)]
dequeuestart = 99
dequeueend = 100
line = input()
while line:
    elems = line.split()
    if elems[0] == 'push_front':
        push_front(dequeue, elems[1])
    elif elems[0] == 'push_back':
        push_back(dequeue, int(elems[1]))
    elif elems[0] == 'pop_front':
        print(pop_front(dequeue))
    elif elems[0] == 'pop_back':
        print(pop_back(dequeue))
    elif elems[0] == 'front':
        print(front(dequeue))
    elif elems[0] == 'back':
        print(back(dequeue))
    elif elems[0] == 'size':
        print(size(dequeue))
    elif elems[0] == 'clear':
        clear(dequeue)
    else:
        exit(dequeue)
        break
    line = input()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If a runtime error occurs, you have to include it in the question. How are we supposed to know what the problem is if you don't show us what went wrong?

Comment: @MechMK1, I am really sorry. I am a newbie here. Now I clarified the explanation. Could you look at it again? –

Comment: I still can't see the runtime error you get. I understand you are new here and I wish you a warm welcome, but please understand that you should include as much information as possible